# Steps to run Spring Boot application as Windows service using winsw

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-integration

How do I run Spring Boot Application as Windows Service, as I'm following [spring doc for winsw](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-service).
Steps:

1. I downloaded distribution package.
2. Downloaded binary that is `winsw.1.19.exe`.

And next they are asking to replace `winsw.exe` to `myApp.exe` and in installation guide they mention I need to edit configuration file, but I'm not getting where is the configuration file where I need to make changes.

Note: *already I have my Spring Boot application is working as service I need to run this service as Windows service.*

Answer (score 9):

The [winsw documentation](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw) mentions what this [configuration file](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/blob/master/doc/xmlConfigFile.md) is while the documentation you're referring to also shows [an example](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/spring-boot-daemon/blob/master/spring-boot-daemon-sample/src/main/dist/service.xml) of how to use it.

The idea is the following, you rename the executable to **myApp.exe** and you create an XML configuration file called **myApp.xml**. I usually configure the service like this (even though it's a bit different from the spring sample):

```xml
<service>
    <id>windowsServiceId</id> <!-- Change this -->
    <name>Readable name of the windows service</name><!-- Change this -->
    <description>Description of the windows service</description><!-- Change this -->
    <workingdirectory>%BASE%\</workingdirectory>
    <logpath>%BASE%\logs</logpath>

    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>-jar my-application.jar</arguments><!-- Change this -->
</service>
```

If you have both in place, you can run the following command to install the windows service:

```
myApp.exe install
```

Comment: I installed winsw.exe and renamed it to mySpringBootApp.exe, created mySpringBootApp.xml, and .xml file is entirely seperate file rite ?  and  (mySpringBootApp.exe and mySpringBootApp.xml are placed in domething like f:\myspringboot\ okay. and now my doubt is in .xml file.

Comment: continuation of above comment, please have a look on my mySpringBootApp.xml **<service> <id>abc</id><name>abc</name> <description>This service as winsw</description><env name="WINSW_HOME" value="F:\Winsw\packagerequestservice"/>
<executable>java</executable><arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -jar "C:\User\Saba\pakagerequest\target\packagerequestservice-default-1.7.0.jar" --httpPort=8080</arguments><logmode>rotate</logmode>
</service>**

Comment: Post the XML in your question as well, also, what exactly doesn't work now?

Comment: logs r generating 1.packagerequestservice-default.err.log 2.packagerequestservice-default.out.log 3.packagerequestservice-default.wrapper.log and in wrapper.log showing this **2016-12-14 13:55:19 - Starting java -Xmx256m -jar C:\Saba\packagerequestservice\target\packagerequestservice-default-1.7.0.jar
2016-12-14 13:55:19 - Started 7852** and in err.log showing this exception **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.** and **Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" **.I already posted xml

Comment: @jamesaq12wsx Yes. First you stop the application (`myApp.exe stop`), then replace the JAR and start the application again (`myApp.exe start`).